# how to add external jar to eclipse projects while not disturbing version control

Tags: android, eclipse, git, version-control

I need to add [roottools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/downloads/detail?name=RootTools-2.4.jar&can=2&q=) to my android project and the way I was going to do it is to add the jar to my git repo and add the jar to my eclipse build configuration as mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/wiki/Usage). The problem is, that the second step does not cause any change in the repo. The changes are only in the `.classpath` file which everyone suggests to add to gitignore. So the question is, how do I add the info that `roottools.jar is included in the build path` to my git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a build tool, like Maven, that is not dependent on an IDE. Then check the build script (pom.xml in the case of Maven) into git.

Then you can still use Eclipse,  as it has support for Maven.

Here is info about how to set up an Android project with Maven: http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted